# Button on cell change images - logic issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Following is a code fragment from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I have added 2 buttons on a Cell.

When the user clicks on Button `A` the image of Button `A` should be `a.png`. And Button `B` should change to `default.png`.

When the user clicks on Button `B` the image of Button `B` should be `b.png`. And Button `A` should change to `default.png`.

How can i do this ?

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method

```
[cell.aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(methodA:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.bButton addTarget:self action:@selector(methodB:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


- (void) methodA:(id) sender {
    [((UIButton *)sender) setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    // How to change the image of Button B to default.png ??
}

- (void) methodB:(id) sender {
        [((UIButton *)sender) setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
 // How to change the image of Button A to default.png ??
}
```

Comment: Is there two static button ?

Comment: are you using custom tableview cell?

Comment: why don't you use segment bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set tag to your buttons like `aButton` has `tag`= 1, and `bButton` has `tag`= 2

```
- (void) methodB:(id) sender {
    UIButton *bButton =((UIButton *)sender) ;
    [bButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)[bButton.superview viewWithTag:bButton.tag-1];
    [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
- (void) methodA:(id) sender {
    UIButton *aButton =((UIButton *)sender) ;
    [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    UIButton *bButton = (UIButton *)[bButton.superview viewWithTag:aButton.tag+1]; //updated here, instead of bButton, put aButton
    [bButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: I get the following warning at `aButton`. `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UIButton *' with an expression of type 'UIView *'`

Comment: I still get the warning. ` Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UIButton *' with an expression of type 'UIView *' `

Comment: @Illep, Plz check again, I have casted `UIView` return from `viewWithTag` to `UIButton`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
[cell.aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(methodToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.bButton addTarget:self action:@selector(methodToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.bButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cell.aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[cell.bButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

cell.aButton.tag == 111;
cell.aButton.tag == 222;
```

Just One method for both Buttons

```
- (void) methodToggle:(id) sender {
    UIButton * btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (btn.tag == 111)
    {
        UIButton * btnAnother = (UIButton *)[[btn superview] viewWithTag:222];
        btnAnother.selected = NO;
    }
    if (btn.tag == 222)
    {
        UIButton * btnAnother = (UIButton *)[[btn superview] viewWithTag:111];
        btnAnother.selected = NO;
    }
    btn.selected = YES;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error `No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'superView'`

Comment: Sorry for spelling mistake its `superview` not `superView`. "v" is small

Answer (score 0):

Inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: add following code

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [cell.aButton setTag:1];
    [cell.aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(methodA:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.aButton setTag:2];
    [cell.bButton addTarget:self action:@selector(methodB:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

Implement the button event handlers as-

```
 - (void) methodA:(id) sender 
{
       UIView *view = [sender superView];
       UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
       [senderButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
       UIButton *otherButton = [view viewWithTag:2];
       [otherButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

 - (void) methodB:(id) sender
{
       UIView * view = [sender superView];
       UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
       [senderButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
       UIButton *otherButton = [view viewWithTag:1];
       [otherButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: I get this warning `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UITableViewCell *' with an expression of type 'UIView *'`

Answer (score 0):

- For both the buttons, set a.png and default.png for UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateSelected respectively
- Now you can simply make the button selected and deselected accordingly and donot worry about the image.

Hope this image gives you another hint.

[image]

**To handle your selection issue**, the best way is to handle it in your tableViewCell class, where you can access both the buttons and write a delegate or callback if required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (void) methodA:(id) sender {
    UIButton *buttonA = (UIButton *)sender;
    CGPoint pointInTable = [field convertPoint:buttonA.bounds.origin toView:_tableView];    

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex];
    //now access the button and change button images
    //cell.aButton setImage:
    //cell.bButton setImage:
}
```

Do the same for button B action.

Note: I recommend using custom tableview cell and handling this button actions inside the custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

Write a CustomCell class which has 2 buttons with target methods and delegate method to notify the table view when buttons clicked. Use this cell in the table view.

In target methods do the image changes(A/B) and fire the delegate method to notify the tableViewController.

You can keep indexpath as a property of cell and pass it with the delegate to tableView.(Set the indexpath for the cell in tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath:)Then you can identify which cell's button was clicked and relevant data object can fetch from your data source.

CustomCell.m

```
 - (IBAction)onButtonAClicked:(id)sender {
       // change your images
       [delegate cellButtonClicked:self.indexpath];
 }
```

TableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

         CustomCell *cell = nil;
         cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

     if(cell == nil) {
          cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
         cell.delegate = self;
    }
         cell.indexpath = indexPath;
 }


 //delegate method
 -(void)cellButtonClicked:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      //get the related data object for the cell using indexPath from    your data source
 }
```